# CORBA::String_var -> I can't assign any value to class field of this type

Tags: c++, string, corba

I have a simple class:

```
class MyExample : public POA_Example
{
   CORBA::String_var field;

   public:
             char* getField();
             void setField(const char* f);
};

char* MyExample::getField()
{
   return CORBA::string_dup(this->field.out());
}

void MyExample::setField(const char* f)
{
   this->field = CORBA::string_dup(f);
}
```

And main app:

```
#include "MyExample.h"
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;

int main()
{
  MyExample e;
  e.setField("Hello");
  cout << e.getField() << "\n";
  return 0;
}
```

I use omniORB and the code I gave above doesn't show anything ... Whats the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using omniORB, you may have to at least call `orb_init()` before string operations will work right. The code you have seems fine otherwise.

(Although you do not have to call `string_dup()` in the `setField()` function, as the `String_var` class will automatically do that when you assign it a `const char*`.)

(And you are leaking memory by calling `e.getField()` in your `cout`. But that shouldn't prevent you from seeing something.)

Comment: thanks! But why do you say that I'm leaking memory by calling `e.getField()` in my `cout`? I don't get it, what's wrong with it? Is there any other way to get this value?

Comment: Well normally you would not make a local call to `getField()`. I assume that is a CORBA interface. When used as a CORBA call, the skeleton will free the memory you dynamically allocate in `string_dup()`. But since you are calling it locally you should catch the result of the call in a String_var so the memory will get cleaned up.

Comment: so how to write a string getter to be able to use `getField` method as CORBA call?

Comment: `String_var s(remoteObject->getField());  cout << s << endl;`

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it's working for me:

```
interface Example
{
    string getString();
    void setString(in string s);
    long getLong();
    void setLong(in long l);

};

#include "example.hh"

class MyExample : public POA_Example
{
    private:

        CORBA::Long l;
        CORBA::String_var s;

    public:

        char* getString();
        void setString(const char* s);
        ::CORBA::Long getLong();
        void setLong(::CORBA::Long l);
};

#include "MyExample.h"

char* MyExample::getString(){
    return CORBA::string_dup(this->s.in());
}

void MyExample::setString(const char* s){
    this->s = CORBA::string_dup(s);
}

::CORBA::Long MyExample::getLong(){
    return this->l;
}

void MyExample::setLong(::CORBA::Long l){
    this->l = l;
}

#include "MyExample.h"
#include <omniORB4/CORBA.h>
#include <omniORB4/Naming.hh>
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::cerr;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    MyExample me;

    me.setLong(1234654);
    cout << "Long: " << me.getLong() << "\n";

    me.setString("Hello");
    cout << "String: " << me.getString() << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```